# Retrieving a JSON formatted string from inside a JSON formatted string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

So I'm using an `HttpClient` to retrieve an `HttpResponseMessage`, where I read the content out as a string:

```
using (var responseStream = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())
{
    var streamContent = responseStream.Result;
}
```

Now, `streamContent` seems to be a JSON formatted string, but what I want to get to is `payload`, which again seems to be a JSON formatted string. The JSON visualizer (VS) gives me this:

```
[JSON]
    [0]
        payload_bytes: 201
        payload: "{"type":"Models.Event.Partyhat","Id":"123"}"
```

I'm having a little trouble getting to `payload` let alone the JSON string residing inside it. I've tried fiddling around with `JsonConvert`, but that didn't help me much.

Any hints?

**Update:**

My attempt at deserializing:

```
var streamContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(responseStream.Result);
```

EDIT 2:

It might be worth adding the actual string:

```json
[{"payload_bytes":201,"payload":"{\"type\":\"Models.Event.Partyhat\",\"Id\":\"123\"}"}]
```

Comment: Can you show your code for deserializing it

Comment: @john Updated the OP.

Comment: `[JSON] [0]` is no json i have ever seen, is that an exact representation of what is returned?

Comment: @TheGeneral He says "The JSON visualizer (VS) gives me this:" so I assume it is a valid JSON but this visualizer displays it like this.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Deserialize the response and then deserialize the payload field.

Comment: if you deserialise to `object` you won't have access to anything which came from the JSON. This is because deserialising is the act of mapping property names in the JSON string to property names in the given type. Object doens't have any matching properties so nothing will be deserialised. Either create a specific class (or hierarchy of classes) to represent your data structure, or you could do a quick-and-dirty job by deserialising to `dynamic` instead.

Comment: @ADyson Deserializing to `JObject` is the common method.

Comment: @Rotem that's another option yes (when using JSON.NET as the deserialiser). I wouldn't like to say if it's common or not, but it's a reasonable approach.

Comment: Your root object is an array, not an object. Even in JavaScript it would be `json[0].payload` to access the payload of the first element, C# is no different.

Comment: @Khaine775 your code has a serious bug. Instead of accessing the *stream* in the `using` block , you access the *task* that will eventually return a stream. Then you *block* the call with `.Result`. Don't do that. Your current code will never close the stream. use `using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())`. You don't need `.Result` after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string jsonText = ...;
dynamic root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonText);        
string payloadText = root[0].payload;  // do not use 'var' here
dynamic payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(payloadText);
```

This gets you `string typeText = payload.type;` as `"Models.Event.Partyhat"`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the code has a serious bug. Instead of accessing the stream in the using block , it accesses the *task* that will eventually return a ... string. Then it *blocks* the call with .Result.

The code should look like this :

```
using (var json= await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())
{
    var jsonArray=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
    var payloadObject=jsonArray[0].payload;
    var payload=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(payloadObject.Value);
}
```

If the calling method isn't asynchronous, it should be turned into one.

By deserializing to `dynamic` you can use the indexer and `.payload` getter directly. The second line uses `.Value` to extract the payload text so it can be deserialized as well.

You can deserialize from the response stream directly instead of reading all the contents as a string. This is usefull when handling large responses since you avoid caching the entire response as a string before deserializing it.

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

using (var stream= await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    var jsonArray=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
    var payloadObject=jsonArray[0].payload;
    var payload=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(payloadObject.Value);
}
```

*A small warning*

Using `.Value` will work only if the value is actually a string, but it will be *very* cheap. The source code for [JValue.Value](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JValue.cs#L697) shows that it returns everything as an `object` without any conversion.

Casting to string will also work only for strings and simple types :

```
string payloadObject=jsonArray[0].payload;
```

This  will go through a couple of levels of indirection before returning the actual value. 
The source code shows that [casting](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs#L1224) actually ends up calling `Convert.ToString(v.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` which is actually [a call to ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1801)

In the end, it will return the same object as `.Value`;

If the payload *isn't* a string then :

1. There would be no need for this question
2. .Value fails for simple types while implicit casting (ie serializing back to string) works
3. Both .Value and implicit casting fail for objects, eg `{\"type\":\"Models.Event.Partyhat\",\"Id\":\"123\"}`

So be careful of the JSON payload, no matter which method you use.

If you can't be certain, you can convert the payload to a string no matter what :

```
string payloadString=jsonArray[0].payload.ToString();
```

Or

```
var payloadObject=jsonArray[0].payload.ToString();
```

Comment: Small nitpick: your `payloadObject` definitely is a `string`, that was the core of the question. And then `payload` is the (dynamic) object.

Comment: @bommelding it's definitely *not* a string. Try it. I copied the code directly from LINQPad after removing the calls to `.Dump()`

Comment: @bommelding your code works because it *casts* the JObject returned from `payload` to a string before assigning it to the variable

Comment: Yes, everything is a JObject if you look at the bits. But logically it must be a string, if that cast fails the input was invalid.

Comment: @bommelding you don't have to look at the bits, call `.GetType()`. The result is actually a JValue. That's not a string.  Your code *casts* it to a string.

Comment: You don't seem to get the concept of "logically". GetType() has to return something castable to string or we have a failure. You do the same with Value, Deserialize only eats strings.

Comment: @bommelding I do actually, I also check the source code and try out variations. If the value is a string, `.Value` returns it directly while your cast calls `ToString()`. If it *isn't*, the cast fails the same as the attempt to deserialize

Comment: @bommelding try removing the quotes surrounding the payload value. You'll get a `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`. That's because it's not logical to assume that the result of deserialization will be anything other than a JToken-derived object. Some of them can be cast to strings as your code did, some not

Comment: What are you on about?  Of course it is a JObject or something, but that is a concession to the weak typing. In a strong typed result it would be  a string property. So in this case: fail fast, fail early and make it a string at the _first_ opportunity. You are propagating the weak typing way too far into the code. It would be flagged in our Code Review.